# Join two tables to return all rows in one and their status in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table 'Settings' contains all the settings a user can enable.
Table 'UserSettings' contains all the settings a user has enabled.

I would like to return all the rows from Table Settings and whether or not they have been saved by a particular user in UserSettings.

Tables are linked using a "settingid" row in each table.

I've tried this using a left join.  is that the best option?

Comment: Have you tried to put together a query for this yet? You should be looking at left join

Comment: Great! Good luck with that. Did you have a **question**?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT s.settingid 
     , u.settingid IS NOT NULL   AS is_set 
  FROM setting s
  LEFT
  JOIN user_setting u 
    ON u.user_id   = ? 
   AND u.settingid = s.settingid
 ORDER
    BY s.settingid
```

We use an outer join to pull matching rows from user_setting. The outer join allows rows without a match to be returned, so we get all rows from `setting`.

Rows that don't have a match will have all NULL values for columns from `user_setting`.

We can expand the second expression in the SELECT list. We're just testing if we found a matching row, and returning a 1 if there was a matching row, or 0 if not.

```
     , IF(u.settingid IS NULL,0,1) AS is_set
```

or a more portable ANSI standards compliant...

```
     , CASE WHEN u.settingid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_set
```